# Java crud edit view

Tags: java, sql, servlets, jpa

I am new to Java and servlets and I have followed this tutorial https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html. I am using my own database which includes 2 tables one for users and the other for cars. I need to be able to show the table's contents depending on which cars are available (ie by using an sql command). How can I do this? The current view shows everything.

Also, I need to create a login screen where I check users against the database. How can I execute an sql command from an xhtml page?

The list page is as follows but I need to display the cars which have a certain field ticked. What must I edit?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListCarsTitle}"></h:outputText>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:form styleClass="jsfcrud_list_form">
            <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{bundle.ListCarsEmpty}" rendered="#{carsController.items.rowCount == 0}"/>
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{carsController.items.rowCount > 0}">
                <h:outputText value="#{carsController.pagination.pageFirstItem + 1}..#{carsController.pagination.pageLastItem + 1}/#{carsController.pagination.itemsCount}"/>&nbsp;
                <h:commandLink action="#{carsController.previous}" value="#{bundle.Previous} #{carsController.pagination.pageSize}" rendered="#{carsController.pagination.hasPreviousPage}"/>&nbsp;
                <h:commandLink action="#{carsController.next}" value="#{bundle.Next} #{carsController.pagination.pageSize}" rendered="#{carsController.pagination.hasNextPage}"/>&nbsp;
                <h:dataTable value="#{carsController.items}" var="item" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" rules="all" style="border:solid 1px">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListCarsTitle_carId}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.carId}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListCarsTitle_isRented}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.isRented}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListCarsTitle_rentalDate}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.rentalDate}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListCarsTitle_rentedDueDate}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.rentedDueDate}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListCarsTitle_paid}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.paid}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListCarsTitle_rentedToUserId}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.rentedToUserId}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="&nbsp;"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:commandLink action="#{carsController.prepareView}" value="#{bundle.ListCarsViewLink}"/>
                        <h:outputText value=" "/>
                        <h:commandLink action="#{carsController.prepareEdit}" value="#{bundle.ListCarsEditLink}"/>
                        <h:outputText value=" "/>
                        <h:commandLink action="#{carsController.destroy}" value="#{bundle.ListCarsDestroyLink}"/>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <br />
            <h:commandLink action="#{carsController.prepareCreate}" value="#{bundle.ListCarsCreateLink}"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <h:link outcome="/index" value="#{bundle.ListCarsIndexLink}"/>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: @яша: scriptlets should be avoided at all cost. Please don't suggest using them. They're obsolete.

Comment: I have added the code of the view page but I am still unsure what I must edit to show the table as I require it

Comment: @JBNizet you have any idea why ?

Comment: @яша Because JSPs are view components, which should only be used to generate HTML markup. Not to execute database query or execute business logic. Java code is better suited at this task. JSPs were invented to avoid having lots of println(html) in the Java code. Cluttering the HTML code with lots of Java instructions is as bad.

Comment: I need to create servlets for login, update etc.. Should I execute a database query here?